# Compilation error when using node.d.ts in TypeScript file

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am working on my first node.js project (for learning purposes) and I would like to use TypeScript as language of choice together with Visual Studio Code (yeah, I'm not looking for easy ways). Source code is here: https://github.com/thecoderok/ukrbash-node 
When I reference  node.d.ts in the source code I am getting lots of compilation

> errors like:urkbash-node\typings\node\node.d.ts(178,36): error TS1005:
>   ';' expected. urkbash-node\typings\node\node.d.ts(425,5): error
>   TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or
>   statement' expected. urkbash-node\typings\node\node.d.ts(425,12):
>   error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum,
>   import or statement' expected.
>   urkbash-node\typings\node\node.d.ts(425,17): error TS1005: ';'
>   expected.

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> errors like:urkbash-node\typings\node\node.d.ts(178,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Considering the content of the line [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e5de5c4daf8cdc33ed60704cd6e8021c99a89f92/node/node.d.ts#L178) Seems like you are using it with TypeScript 1.4 (which doesn't have union types). Please update VS Code to latest to use TS 1.5